# Assume that $1a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n=1$, where the $a_j$ are real numbers...

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

Assume that
$$
1a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n=1,
$$
where the $a_j$ are real numbers.
As a function of $n$, what is the minimum value of
$$1a_1^2+2a_2^2+\cdots+na_n^2$$

There is a similar question on Math StackExchange, but nobody gave a solid and conclusive answer, so I felt the need to repeat it here. I also think this question should be solved using Cauchy-Schwarz, Mean Inequality Chain, or Trivial Inequality, but I would appreciate any answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I realized, but the other question did not have a good or helpful answer.

Comment: Never use ` \[...\]` in titles.

Comment: Did - Okay, but just curious, what difference does it make?

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answer to the other question, you should explain what you think is inadequate or not explained well.  You should also link to the other question so people can see what is there.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $a1^2 + ....  \ge \sqrt[n]{n!\prod a_i^2}$ with equality holding if $ia_i^2 = ja_i^2$.  So  $a_j^2 = N/k$ so $a_j = \sqrt N/\sqrt j$ so $1 = \sqrt{N} \sum  i\sqrt{i}$.

Comment: @QuantumPizza The hint in the top answer there is a correct way to solve the problem, and I'd argue it's the most helpful hint one could give.  Could you elaborate on what you think could be better about it?

Comment: This spends vertical space on nothing, here and on the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\;\sigma = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k a_k^2 =
\sum_{k=1}^n \big(\underbrace{k(a_k - \sigma)^2}_I + \underbrace{2\sigma k(a_k - \sigma)}_J + k\sigma^2\big)$$

Notice the contribution for the first term $I$ is non-negative and
the contribution from the middle term $J$ vanishes, i.e.

$$J = 2\sigma\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k(a_k - \sigma)\right) = 2\sigma \left(\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k - \sigma\sum_{k=1}^n k\right) = 2\sigma\left(1 - \frac{\sigma}{\sigma}\right) = 0$$

We obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k^2 \ge \sigma^2 \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma} = \sigma = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$
Since this lower bound is achieved when all $a_k = \sigma$, the minimum value of the sum at hand is $\sigma$.

Comment: @ achille hui Sorry about that, wasn't reading the problem correctly :P

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is nice but I'd just like to expand on the Cauchy inequality response in the linked question, since I think that's the most straightforward and illuminating way to do it (if you're going to study inner product spaces and their connection to matrices). No cleverness needed.  Most of this post is just clarifying notation!

Let the notation $\vec{\mathbb{1}}$ denote the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ with all entries identically $1$, and $H$ be the matrix with diagonal elements $1,\cdots, n$

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 3 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $H$ is a positive definite real symmetric matrix, it defines an inner product as $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle_H = \vec{x}^T H \vec{y}$, for which the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality holds.

Note that your problem is now to minimize $$||a||_H \ \ \ \ \text{subject to} \ \ \  \langle \vec{\mathbb{1}}, \vec{a} \rangle_H = 1$$

Now the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality gives us exactly that 
$$1 = |\langle \vec{\mathbb{1}}, \vec{a}  \rangle_H| \leq ||\vec{\mathbb{1}}||_H||\vec{a}||_H = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k^2$$ where **equality holds if and only if $\vec{a}$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec{\mathbb{1}}$** (that's a very important part of the inequality's full statement!!)

This last part guarantees that $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ minimizes $\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k^2$ and also that this value is attained uniquely by $\vec{a} = \frac{\vec{\mathbb{1}}}{||\vec{\mathbb{1}}||_H}$

Answer (score 0):

A theorem about strictly convex functions: For  $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,$ if  $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R,$ then whenever $w_1,...,w_n$ are non-negative reals with $\sum_{j=1}^nw_j=1,$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ are in  $\mathbb R,$ then $$\sum_{j=1}^nw_jf(a_j)\geq f\left(\sum_{j=1}^nw_ja_j\right)$$ with equality iff $a_i=a_j$ whenever $w_i\ne 0\ne w_j.$

Let $f(x)=x^2$. Let  $w_j=\frac {j}{(n^2+n)/2}$ for $j=1,...,n.$ Let  $\sum_{j=1}^nja_j=1.$ The above theorem, by a direct calculation, implies that $\sum_{j=1}^nj a_j^2\geq 2/(n^2+n),$ with equality iff $a_j=2/(n^2+n)$ for all $j$.